# C# AWS Lambda and Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I have a foreach loop running inside an AWS lambda, with a Thread.Sleep(2000) to throttle execution. However, the code doesn't seem to pause: I've logged timestamps before and after its execution. Here's a simplified version of the method:

```
        private async Task<string> ExecuteAutoRetryRequest(string url)
        {
            string html = String.Empty;
            int numberOfRetry = 3;
            while (numberOfRetry > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    html = await ExecuteGetRequest(url);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html) && !html.Contains("Access Denied"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await LogException(ex.Message);
                }

                // Wait two seconds and try again
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                numberOfRetry--;
            }

            return html;
        }
```

I call it like so `var htmlSnapShotResult = await ExecuteAutoRetryRequest(url);`

I'm sure this is something basic about how lambdas operate that I'm unaware of, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example of your code and where you are seeing the issue?

Comment: Try `await Task.Delay(2000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexander's comment above is the correct answer: the following executes the pause correctly:

`await Task.Delay(2000);`